# Ignore Default Gravity In Pipeline - Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

Forgive me if there is already another post addressing something like this, but I haven't found it yet. I'm trying to get my object to ignore the default gravity field and move between the walls of the pipe in the image below:

[image]

The effect I'm trying to achieve is to allow my player (cube) to exit with a different rotation/spin when leaving the pipe as it falls back toward the ground.

I've seen an attractor script for planetary bodies elsewhere, but I'm not sure those apply to this scenario or not. Obviously, I'm planning on using a mesh collidor for my pipeline in the image (I created this in Blender) and the faces are inverted.

If I need to create a script for this, where would I start? Which object would I apply this script to and in which way?

Comment: Are you trying to move the objects through the pipe, or just change how they're ejected?

Comment: Just change it so that a player object can move left and right inside the pipe in full rotation. Right now I think gravity pulls it down toward the ground but I know that's not the only factor, since I tried moving left and right with the player with gravity turned off.